# Weird equation to setup an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

In page 3 of the book *The theory of differential equations* second edition of Kelley and Peterson I read the following

> **Example $1.4$** (non uniqueness of solutions to IVP) If we drop an object from a bridge of height $h$ at time $t=0$ (assuming constant acceleration of gravity and negligible air resistance), then the height of the object after $t$ units of time is $x(t)=-\frac12gt^2+h$. The velocity at time $t$ is $x'(t)=-gt$, so by eliminating $t$, we are led to the IVP
>
> $$x'=f(t,x):=-\sqrt{2g|h-x|},\quad x(0)=h\tag1$$

*Note: here IVP means initial value problem.*

I dont see how we get the absolute value on $(1)$. I have that

$$x=-\frac12gt^2+h\implies t=\sqrt{2(h-x)g^{-1}}\implies x'=f(t,x)=-\sqrt{2g(h-x)}$$

If instead we choose $t=-\sqrt{2(h-x)g^{-1}}$ then we get $$x'=\sqrt{2g(h-x)}$$

Moreover: the problem, as said in the comments, is not trivial because after its said that the function $f(t,x):=-\sqrt{2g|h-x|}$ is not partially differentiable respect to $x$ at $x=h$, what is a consequence of the absolute value and the assumption that is possible that $x>h$.

Comment: You can't choose $t=-\sqrt{\text{stuff}}$ in this model because $t$ is nonnegative. Your first equation is right; because the object is falling, $x<h$, hence $|h-x|=h-x$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I knew it, I just had shown that formally we cant get the absolute value from this choice of $t$. Of course we can say that $x(t)\le h$ so $|h-x|=h-x$, anyway it seems strange the use of the absolute value.

Comment: It seems they used $|h-x|$ just so the expression is *defined* when $x>h$. Otherwise they won't be able to differentiate with respect to $x$ near $h$. The point is to illustrate an issue with uniqueness of solutions, not to illustrate the solution to a physical problem.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I see, but if the domain of $x$ is such that $h\ge x$ for all $t$ then we can differentiate safely respect to $x$ because $$\lim_{x\to h}\frac{|h-x|-h}{h-x}=\lim_{x\to h^-}\frac{|h-x|-h}{h-x}$$ That is: there is not lateral limit by the right of $h$ for this function.